# Dynamically Building a TreeView or Bindable Source in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a list of strings, a general formatting of:

"Header_subheader1_subheader2_item"

The problem is the actual string can vary in the amount of subheaders it contains.  It might not have any, it may have 3 or 4. I've been trying to find a way to easily create a TreeView directly, or better yet a good bindable source I can create inside my ViewModel, and have so far come up empty as far as this type of scenario is concerned.

Looking for suggestions!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that best option will be to create list of Item classes with Header and ListOfSubheaders properties. On creation it will parse your strings, also you will be able to add logic in it and after that easily create TreeView

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll look at that!